# IE9 Textbox Autocomplition coming on outside on a textareabox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

While using IE9 I found a strange problem on textbox entry the code is following

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox_1" value="">
```

When after the first entry when I am going to put another value here then Autocomplition text is coming outside on a textarea. Is there any way to turn this off

Comment: Does this problem occur on real textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete="off" attribute works in everything but Opera. May be what you need.

I don't really see why autocomplete is a problem though. It is there to aid the user, therefore giving them a better experience. Removing this option just makes the users experience worse.